# How is OpenPlug able to build on windows?

Tags: ios, windows, build, openplug

OpenPlug is a app builder that runs on mac and windows.

http://developer.openplug.com/learn-more//362-cr14

"iOS distribution signing on Windows and Mac

Sign your iOS applications for distribution right from OpenPlug Studio. There is no more need for signing with Xcode! IPA package signature for both development and iTunes distribution was completed with the additional support of:

Apple Push Notification service
in App purchase
And it runs seamlessly on Mac and Windows machines."

Apple, I am sure will ban Openplug apps if there isn't an agreement. 
Just seen that [marmalade SDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/)  can also build on windows.

How are they allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the product manager for the OpenPlug tools.

Our tools are not the only ones that allow IPA signing on Windows (you mentioned marmalade, but there is also Adobe CS5/AIR/Flash Builder, and certainly others ...)

As far as I know, Apple hasn't banned any app built with those tools on the ground that they were developed on a non-Apple-branded computer.

For publishing your app you anyway need to access iTunes Connect from a Mac.

Having the possibility to sign IPAs on Windows facilitates the dev/debug cycle on device if you are a developer with a Windows host.

Technically, the signing tools are available open source from the Mach open source distribution of MacOSX. You can refer to the comments section of this post on Corona's blog (another app development tool) for discussion about legalities: http://blog.anscamobile.com/2010/03/does-flash-cs5-for-windows-violate-the-iphone-developer-agreement/.

The last time I looked at Apple's agreements, its only the "SDK" (i.e. xCode and associated iOS SDK) that was only allowed for use on Apple-branded computers only.

Hope this helps

Guilhem